# Bash script : Get user input in a terminal that is not focus on

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

In a open Terminal, I use to get user input like this from my script :

```
while true
do
    echo "Please scan your barcode :"
    read string
    result=`node node.js $string`
    echo "--> $result"
    // Launch an image viewer (feh)
    sh ./feh.sh $result
done
```

This script reads user input because Terminal is focus on, but when it launches the image viewer (in fullscreen mode), the Terminal becomes itself in background of the image viewer. So if the user type on his keyboard, the script couldn't read anything.

Do you know how to get the user inputs even if the terminal window is in background of the image viewer ?

Comment: [zenity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity), or its KDE counterpart, kdialog, offer scripts an easy way to request user input *via GUI elements*. Instead of having the terminal itself receive the input, you'd pop up a small window requesting input from the user. I don't know your application, perhaps this is useful for you. -- `data=$(zenity --entry --text="Please enter your data" --entry-text="default")` / `data=$(kdialog --inputbox "Please enter your data" "default")`

Comment: Yes, agree with @DevSolar you could use kdialog on KDE. But how does your script go beyond read string and launch image viewer ? read call blocks the execution until user enters input.

Comment: Actually, I just want the user to view images loaded in viewer, nothing more, nothing less. The only way for him to change images is to scan a barcode but he never have to see a prompt or a GUI dialog.